# How to allow page breaks within footnotes, when using dblfnote?

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, footnotes

Is it possible to let footnotes set in two columns with `dblfnote` break across pages? In the following MWE note 3 is so long that it goes to a second page together with the third paragraph, but I want note 3 to start on the first page and continue on the second page because otherwise I got lot of white space on the first page.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{dblfnote}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1] 
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just compile your code and there is no problem (What I Get Is What YOU Want)  remark .log:Package: dblfnote 1999/07/14 v1.0

Comment: sorry the problem was with my lipsum package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This doesn't answer the question, but you can use `eledmac` instead of `dblfnote` to get two columns footnotes.

With `eledmac` long footnotes are split across pages.

Here's your example with `eledmac`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\twocolfootfmtX}{\raggedright}{}{}{}

\foottwocolX{A}

\let\footnote\footnoteA

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this idea … actually I’m using `eledmac` already. But unfortunately the layout of the two columns isn’t that flexible (see my follow-up question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/234258/4918).

Comment: @Tobi I've added more formatting...

Comment: Thanks, maybe you like to remove the formatting code from here and add it as an answer to my other question …

Comment: @Tobi I will...