# How to format eledmac’s two-column footnotes

Tags: footnotes, eledmac

After karlkoeller cam up with a solution for [How to allow page breaks within footnotes, when using dblfnote?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232957/4918) I really like to use it but unfortunately the styling of the footnotes isn’t flexible enough. The following MWE shows war I want to have and what I got so far …

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

% WHAT I WANT
%\deffootnotemark{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark}}
%\usepackage{dblfnote}% Setzt die Fußnoten zweispaltig
%   \DFNtrysingle
%   \renewcommand\footnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}%
%        \vspace*{2.6pt}%
%   }
%   \setlength{\DFNcolumnsep}{1.5em}
%   \setlength{\skip\footins}{1\baselineskip plus 20pt minus 5pt}
%\deffootnote{1.4em}{1em}{%
%   \makebox[1.4em][l]{\thefootnotemark}%
%}
%\setkomafont{footnote}{\itshape}

% WHAT I GOT
\usepackage{eledmac,etoolbox}
   \patchcmd{\twocolfootfmtX}{\raggedright}{}{}{}
   \foottwocolX{C}

   \renewcommand\Cfootnoterule{\vspace*{-3pt}\vspace*{2.6pt}}
   \setlength{\skip\Cfootins}{1\baselineskip plus 20pt minus 5pt}

   \Xhangindent[C]{1.4em}
   \afternumberinfootnote[C]{0em}
   \boxlinenum[C]{1.4em}

   \notenumfontX[C]{\itshape}

   \newlength{\fncolwidth}
      \setlength{\fncolwidth}{0.5\textwidth}
      \addtolength{\fncolwidth}{-0.75em}
   \hsizetwocol[C]{\fncolwidth}

   \let\footnote\footnoteC


\usepackage{lipsum}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

In my real document I furthermore got the problem, that the column gap doesn’t work:

[image: trouble with column spacing]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With some formatting, here is more or less what you are trying to achieve...

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\notenumfontX[C]{\itshape}
\hsizetwocolX[C]{\dimexpr.5\columnwidth-.75em\relax}
\hangindentX[C]{1.4em}

\renewcommand\footnoteruleC{\relax}
\setlength{\skip\footinsC}{1\baselineskip plus 20pt minus 5pt}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\twocolfootfmtX}[2]{%
   \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \@nameuse{@thefnmark#1}%
   }%
  \normal@pars
  \everypar{\hangindent=\csuse{hangindentX@#1}}%
  \hsize \csuse{hsizetwocolX@#1}
  \parindent=\z@
%%%  \parfillskip=0pt \@plus 1fil
  \tolerance=5000\relax
  \leavevmode
  {\csuse{notenumfontX@#1}\@nameuse{footfootmark#1}\strut%\enspace
    #2\strut\par}\allowbreak}
\makeatother

\foottwocolX{C}

\let\footnote\footnoteC

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\begin{document}
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
   \lipsum[2-4]\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this code. Is it possible to control the vertical space between the notes and to make it a little flexible so that both columns flush at the bottom (in the example the left one is slightly higher)?

Answer (score 2):

The column gap doesn't work because you don't set it.

`\hsizetwocol[C]{\fncolwidth}` is for setting column width for critical notes.

`\hsizetwocolX[C]{\fncolwidth}` is for setting column width for familiar notes.

Comment: Actually i tried both, but it seems I found a bug … see https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/259

Answer (score 2):

This is the fromat I created based on karl's answer:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

\usepackage{eledmac}

\notenumfontX[C]{\itshape}% actually this will be
                          % a condenses upright font

\renewcommand\footnoteruleC{\relax}
\setlength{\skip\footinsC}{1\baselineskip plus 20pt minus 5pt}

\hsizetwocolX[C]{\dimexpr.5\columnwidth-.75em\relax}
\hangindentX[C]{1.4em}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\twocolfootfmtX}[2]{%
   \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
      \@nameuse{@thefnmark#1}%
   }%
   \normal@pars
   %\everypar{\hangindent=\csuse{hangindentX@#1}}%
   \hsize \csuse{hsizetwocolX@#1}
   \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
   %\addtolength{\parindent}{\csuse{hangindentX@#1}}
   %%%  \parfillskip=0pt \@plus 1fil
   \tolerance=5000\relax
   \leavevmode
   {%
      \hspace*{-\parindent}%
      \csuse{notenumfontX@#1}%
      \makebox[1.4em][l]{%
         \textbf{\@nameuse{@thefnmark#1}}%
         %\strut%\enspace
      }%
   #2\strut\par
   }%
   \allowbreak
}
\renewcommand*{\normalbodyfootmarkX}[1]{%
   \textsuperscript{\@nameuse{@thefnmark#1}}%
}
\makeatother

\foottwocolX{C}
\let\footnote\footnoteC

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[1]} \lipsum[1]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[3]
   Lipsum\footnote{\lipsum[2-4]} \lipsum[2]
   \lipsum[2-4]\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

Comment: Since you've modified the code, I'll answer here. Simply remove the `%` before `\strut` in the line `%\strut%\enspace`.

Comment: @karlkoeller: Thanks, adding the `\strut` back again actually makes both columns aligned. But could you explain, where the vertical space comes from? And why the baselineskip is to small if I remove both `\strut`s?

Comment: I'm sorry, no....

Comment: you shoul note override `\twocolfootfmtX`.Except for the bug with geometry (which you didn't speak here), it's preferable to ask for new LaTeX hooks. Any new \renwcommand is problematic for the compatibility with future version of eledmac.

Comment: for example, for the footnotemark in box, you could use

Comment: `\renewcommand{\footfootmarkC}{\makebox[1.4em]{\textbf{\arabic{footnoteC}}}}`

Comment: @Maïeul: Thanks I also preferr the build in ways but didn't found out the way to go. I guess I have to read the manual again and see what it offers …

Comment: yes handbook is quite complex. Many things created in the time of ledmac are explained in the section about code `Implementation overview` and after, and not in the main text. But it should not the case for feature added by eledmac, which are documented two time

Comment: 1) one time from user point of view 2) one time from dev point of view.